# Visual Studio Mobile Center - run Xamarin UI test - error

Tags: xamarin, npm, xamarin.forms, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

I used Visual Studio Mobile Center for test my Xamarin Forms Android app.
This is my steps:

1.I installed node.js

2.I installed

```
 npm install -g mobile-center-cli
```

3. I logged in mobile center
4. I running command

   ```
   mobile-center test run uitest --app  ...
   ```

and get error:

```
Preparing tests... done.
Validating arguments... done.
Creating new test run... done.
Validating application file... done.
Uploading application file... failed.
Command failed, EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\mobile-center-upload11713-4444
2-1xbddnw.571q7ojdddmi\apps\com.my.package-Signed_resigned.apk'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Review the answers provided here : https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826

Comment: Thank you. This is work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. I removed node.js  6.9.5 ans installed node.js 7.5.0(last version). This is work for me.